# SVD Decomposition of Positive Semi Definite 2d-Convolutions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-analysis, convolution, svd

I am interested in 2d convolutions. Specifically, I am interested in convex [CNN networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) which happens if (and only if?) their 2d convolutional layers are PSD (since this makes them monotone, and since they were the only non-monootone layers in the CNN, so my doing so the CNN consists of only convex & monotone layers; thus, it is convex).

Now, to the question itself:
A 1d convolution can be seen as a Toeplitz matrix. Thus, if it's a PSD, then its SVD decomposition, [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) is just $A = \sum_{k=1}^r d_k v(f_k) v(f_k)^\text{H} = VDV^\text{H}$ where V is the Vandermonde matrix.

Now, in the 2d case: a 2d convolution is a **doubly blocked Toeplitz matrix** (and even doubly block circulant matrix). [Here](https://github.com/alisaaalehi/convolution_as_multiplication/blob/main/Convolution_as_multiplication.ipynb) we can see a nice demonstration of how to convert each 2d convolution into a doubly blocked Toeplitz matrix.
I still can't figure out what does it mean about the SVD decomposition of PSD 2d convolutions. How does it look?

Your help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly,
$A = \sum_{k=1}^r d_k v(f_k) v(f_k)^\text{H} = VDV^\text{H}$
is not the SVD of a Toeplitz matrix, neither does the Wikipedia page claim that. That is known as the "Vandermonde decomposition" and the claim is that a rank appropriate PSD Toeplitz matrix can be *uniquely* factorized as such (Carathéodory and Fejér, 1911). For a fairly simple proof of this decomposition under stronger assumptions that $A$ is PD and Hermitian see the appendix of [Bäckström](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6601660). Note that there is a typo on equation 33, it should be $VA = \Lambda$.

Now to answer your question. The SVD looks like it always does. I assume you are interested in the Vandemonde decomposition. This decomposition can be generalized for multilevel Toeplitz matrices, i.e. for $n$-times block Toeplitz matrices (see [Yang et al.](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2016.2553041), theorem 1).

In your case. For a PSD **doubly blocked** Toeplitz matrix, $T$, with rank$(T) = r <\min \{n_1, n_2 \}$ we have

$$ A = \sum_{k=1}^r d_k v(f_{:k}) v(f_{:k})^\text{H} = V(f)DV(f)^H $$
where $f \in [0,1]^{2 \times r}$ and $f_{:k}$ is the $k$:th column of $f$. Furthermore,
$v(f_{:k}) := v_{n_1}(f_{1k}) \otimes v_{n_2}(f_{2k}) \in \mathbb{C}^{n_1\cdot n_2}$ where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and thus
$V(f) := [v(f_{:1}), v(f_{:2}), ..., v(f_{:r})] = V_{n_1}(f_{1:}) \star V_{n_2}(f_{2:}) \in \mathbb{C}^{n_1 \cdot n_2 \times r}$
where $\star$ is the Khatri-Rao product (column-wise Kronecker product). $V_{n_j}(f_{j:}), \: j=1,2$ is a Vandermonde matrix but $V(f)$ is not.

A few notes:

- $v_{n_1}(f_{1k}) = [1, e^{i2\pi f_{1k}}, ..., e^{i2\pi(n-1) f_{1k}}]^T \in \mathbb{C}^{n_1}$ like in the regular (single block) Toeplitz case
- $n_j, \: j = 1,2$  is the dimension of level $j$. So, following the notation in [your resource](https://github.com/alisaaalehi/convolution_as_multiplication/blob/main/Convolution_as_multiplication.ipynb) for double block Toeplitz, $n_1$ is the dimension of $A$ and $n_2$ is the dimension of $A_{ij}$. Note that all $A_{ij}$ most be the same dimensions, otherwise $A$ is not Toeplitz.
- If $r = \min \{ n_1, n_2 \}$ then the Vandermonde decomposition is no longer unique.

Comment: Thanks! Nice explanation! :)